# Issue with generating models using Ember CLI and Ember-localstorage-dapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am learning Ember and have been watching the Microsoft videos at the following URL. https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/creating-web-applications-with-ember-15692?l=0mGK6g00B_7405244527

I was making good progress until the generated Models and ended up with `import DS from` and then I read a post and found out that is the new behavior. I was able to modify the model code accordingly and get mine to work. Phew...

I then hit around 7:00 into the above video when they start to implement `Ember-localstorage-adapter` and the Git instructions are completely different than whats on Git today even though the version is the same. I only have the two models and when I look at the git page for the adapter I see this:

```
// app/serializers/application.js
import { LSSerializer } from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';

export default LSSerializer.extend();

// app/adapters/application.js
import LSAdapter from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';

export default LSAdapter.extend({
namespace: 'yournamespace'
});
```

I don't have app/serializers or adapters so I'm totally lost.

I'm really hoping I don't have to abort this video as there aren't really any other up-to-date videos out there on Ember. I've tried a bunch of others and they were dated or ill-suited for a beginner such as myself.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what's your question? :)

Comment: Apologies, I should have asked a clear question. I'm wondering what the solution is so that I can resume the lessons. I will attempt to generate them in the morning once I've rested and see if that works.

Comment: If you are learning Ember, there is a totally free, up to date and complex tutorial also: http://yoember.com Happy learning! ;)

Comment: Hi Zoltan. That was my go to resource, however, I couldn't get past the end of the second section where you create a controller for contact. I applied what I learned and wound up with a different format and the only example was using a model rather than a controller. I've used allot of learning resources before and they always include source code at each step. They don't say here is an example that is totally different than what we showed you because we are using a different format later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have app/serializers or adapters so I'm totally lost.

Just generate them using:

```
ember g serializer application
ember g adapter application
```

And then copy content from whatever page you check to see if everything's up to date to these files.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I will do this in the morning. Is this something I only need to do once per Ember project?

Comment: Yes. You have to check in small steps one-by-one if things that you do are up-to-date. With these 2 files you've mentioned you can just generate them, copy content with exporting these LSAdapter and LSSerializer and hope everything will work at least with these files.